# unserialize function in php ads extra slashes to the result string

Tags: php

this is a serialized form:

```
 [featureimg520_624] => a:2:{s:9:"image_url";s:47:"2019/05/2019-05-27-06-07-02keerthy-suresh2.jpeg"
```

after unserialize I get

```
 "image_url":"2019\/05\/2019-05-27-06-07-02keerthy-suresh2.jpeg"
```

with extra backslashes

I tried stripcslashes, stripslashes, str_replace

but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which is adding those backslashes. You can avoid them by using the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option to that function:

```
$string = 'a:1:{s:9:"image_url";s:47:"2019/05/2019-05-27-06-07-02keerthy-suresh2.jpeg";}';
$array = unserialize($string);
echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Output:

```
{"image_url":"2019/05/2019-05-27-06-07-02keerthy-suresh2.jpeg"}
```